# Do drumstick flowers reduce sexual dysfunction?

Tags: medical-science

[TheHealthSite](http://www.thehealthsite.com/diseases-conditions/use-drumstick-flowers-to-remedy-erectile-dysfunction-pa0115/) claims that a compound called terigospermin, found in the flowers of the [drumstick plant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moringa_oleifera) resolves erectile dysfunction.

> This property of drumstick is mainly due to a compound called terigospermin that helps strengthen and increase the number (sperm count) and motility of sperm. Also, a study published in the American Journal Of Neuroscience [1] found the the plant worked by inhibiting the production of a particular compound and helped improve libido and performance. Also known as ‘Indian Viagra’, drumstick flowers are extremely effective when it comes to resolving common problems like erectile dysfunction and infertility.

Is this true?

Answer (score 1):

The claim about the ([non-existent](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pccompound/?term=terigospermin)) "terigospermin" must surely be referring to [pterygospermin](http://pubchem.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/compound/72201063) which is found in [Moringa pterygosperma](http://www.himalayawellness.com/herbfinder/moringa-pterygosperma.htm) (Drumstick, Horse Radish).

It does appear to have some effects as a painkiller and anti-inflammatory in **lab animals** as found in [*Analgesic, Anti-inflammatory and Local Anaesthetic Activity of Moringa pterygosperma in Laboratory Animals*](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1076/phbi.41.4.248.15670#.VbYxm_mu_Zc)

> Analgesic activity was tested in mice using various doses orally. Acetic acid-induced writhing episodes were significantly and dose-dependently reduced. At the same dose, its anti-inflammatory activity was also tested. Carrageenin (a standard inflammatory agent)-induced paw edema in mice was significantly reduced after oral administration. Furthermore, its local anaesthetic activity were tested in frog and guinea pig models, and it was seen that in both animals, the plant (root bark) produces significant local anaesthetic activity.

As for the claim of use treating erectile dysfunction this was looked at in research to some extent.

The source they cite, *[Moringa oleiferaleaves extract attenuates male sexual dysfunction.](http://miracletrees.org/moringa-doc/moringa-leaves-attenuates-male-sexual-ysfunction.pdf)* is purely about rats.

> The results showed that after single administration, rats subjected to M.oleifera extract at dose of 10 mg kg-1 BW significantly enhanced mounting number. When the treatment was prolonged to 7 days rats subjected to the low dose of extract showed the enhanced intromission number whereas rats subjected to high dose of extract showed the enhanced mounting number.

[Effect of Aqueous Extract of Moringa oleifera Seed on Sexual Activity of Male Albino Rats](http://researchtrend.net/bf42/19%20DR%20ZADE%20VAIBHAVE.pdf)

> Oraladministration of aqueous extract at doses of 100, 200 and 500 mg/kg significantly increased the Mounting Frequency, Intromission Frequency and Ejaculation latency with reduction in Mounting Latency, Intromission Latency and Post Ejaculatory Interval. It also significantly increased the libido and sperm count in experimental animal.

[Effects of Increasing Aqueous Root Extract of Moringa oleifera on Sperm Production of Albino Rats.](http://www.ajol.info/index.php/agrosh/article/view/93724)

> The phytochemical effects of aqueous extract of root on sperm production of White albino rats were investigated. The rats were divided into five treatment dose levels; 0 (5.0 ml saline); 5.0; 10.0; 15.0 and 20.0 mls consisting five (5) animals per treatment and administered orally for 10 days using aqueous extract of Moringa oleifera roots. The extract tested positive to alkaloid, flavonoids, saponin and cyanogenic glycosides as the active ingredient and showed negative to tannin and oxalates. The results also showed increased (p<0.05) mass activity, progressive motility, sperm concentration and semen output in the treated rats. The histological examination revealed no lesion on the testis. The findings of this study indicated that the active ingredient from Moringa oleifera could significantly increase sperm production.

Disclaimer: may not apply to you if you are not a Male Albino Rat.

It appears to be bad for Guinea Pigs Testis.

[Methanolic Extract of Moringa oleifera Lam Roots is Not Testis-Friendly to Guinea Pigs](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Blessing_Didia/publication/265947877_Methanolic_Extract_of_Moringa_oleifera_Lam_Roots_is_Not_Testis-Friendly_to_Guinea_Pigs/links/54d1e8a70cf28370d0e164ca.pdf)

> From the present study we infer that Methanolic extract of  Moringa oleifera lam root causes distortion of the histo-architecture of the testis of guinea pigs, which is time and dose-dependent

**I couldn't find any human trials on treating sexual dysfunction** so I can't confirm or deny if it can be used effectively in treating sexual dysfunction in humans.

Personally I wouldn't just go out and eat a load, given what it did to the Guinea Pigs.

The papers don't limit it to Pterygospermin, so Pterygospermin may be totally uninvolved and the effects found in rodent trials may be due to any of the other compounds found in the plant. In the case of the cited study, they just ground up the leaves.